# is there a way to change CSS from a foreign page modify it and then publish it on the fly

Tags: html, css

**This is my case:**

There is an ugly page service. My idea is to get HTML and CSS from that page, then modify the CSS with my custom CSS and publish it on the fly using the foreign data (HTML) and my CSS.
How can it be done?, is there a WEB service with that function on line?, What is this idea called?

Comment: What I would try: first remove all the `style` attributes of all elements and then remove the styles in the `head` of the document. Then add a `style` DOM element in the doc's head that points to your css. Not sure if this idea works.

Answer (score 0):

First check if this service provide a JSON object before trying to work with HTML. if it provide you with JSON object then its very easy to build the UI you want.

if not then parse the html code get only the needed data then build your custom HTML

search for parsing HTML pages.